# Assigning values to children of a control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to assign text to the textbox in the stackpanel. There will be 20 or 25 textbox in total. My code can only assign a value to the first item.

XAML

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Products">
    <TextBox Height="35" FontSize="18"/>
    <TextBox Height="35" FontSize="18"/>
    <TextBox Height="35" FontSize="18"/>
    <TextBox Height="35" FontSize="18"/>
    <TextBox Height="35" FontSize="18"/>
    <TextBox Height="35" FontSize="18"/>
    <TextBox Height="35" FontSize="18"/>
    <TextBox Height="35" FontSize="18"/>
    <TextBox Height="35" FontSize="18"/>
    <TextBox Height="35" FontSize="18"/>
</StackPanel>
```

CODE

```
foreach (Control control in Products.Children) // Ürünler listeleniyor
{
    if (control.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
        ((TextBox)control).Text = "messages";
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the first one just Products.Children[0] as TextBox ?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define your starting point in your example the stackpanel named "Products":

```
Control products = (Control)Root.FindName("Products");
```

Secondly you can use VisualTreeHelper to run through all of its child controls which are textboxes and change their text:

```
int nChildCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(products );
for (int i = 0; i <= nChildCount - 1; i++){
   Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(products , i);
   if (v.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)){
      v.text="my new text";
   }
}
```

Comment: "v.text =" There is no "text" attribute for the "v" definition.
Error description:
'Visual' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no accessible extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'Visual' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please try -> DependencyObject v = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(products , i);

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Products.Children.Count; i++)
{
      var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(Products, i);
      if (child.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
      {
           ((TextBox)child).Text = i + "messages";
      }                
}
```

It worked this way.